# Cómo hacer un WHERE IN con una lista de múltiples valores?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Tengo esto:
    `lista = [6575,7567,4545,6766,444,6565,66,54545,65456,666,1233]
    consulta.execute("""SELECT Producto,
    Numero_de_serie,
    Fecha,
    FROM test WHERE (Numero_de_serie = lista)`
Quiero listar todos los productos que contengan solo y exclusivamente los números de serie de la lista `lista` y ese código no me funciona.
Tampoco me funciona `(Numero_de_serie = lista[0])` para listar solo ese número de serie ni tampoco `(Numero_de_serie in (lista))` ni `(Numero_de_serie in (lista[0],lista[1],lista[2]))`.
Podría ponerlos todos así: `(Numero_de_serie in (6575,7567,4545,6766))`ya que esto sí funciona pero la lista real es de 20 o 30 números y además se introducen todos mediante un `input` conformando la lista.
Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Algo así debería funcionar : where numero_de_serie in (select numeros_de_serie from lista)

Comment: Hola @FederHico Gracias por contestar. He probado tu código pero no funciona. Me aparece esto: `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: lista`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes formatear la query insertando dinámicamente el número parámetros en función de la longitud de  la lista. Esto permite por otro lado mantenerla parametrizada para protegerse contra la inyección de código.

```
query_patt = """
    SELECT
        Producto,
        Numero_de_serie,
        Fecha
    FROM test WHERE Numero_de_serie IN ({}) 
    """

lista = [6575, 7567, 4545, 6766, 444, 565, 66, 54545, 65456, 666, 1233]

query = query_patt.format(','.join('?' * len(lista)))
consulta.execute(query, lista)
```

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import os
import sqlite3



con = sqlite3.connect("test_db.sqlite3")
cur = con.cursor()

query = """
    CREATE TABLE test (
        Producto text NOT NULL,
        Numero_de_serie integer NOT NULL
        )
    """
cur.execute(query)

query = "INSERT INTO test (Producto, Numero_de_serie) VALUES (?, ?)"
cur.execute(query, ("Producto a", 1))
cur.execute(query, ("Producto b", 2))
cur.execute(query, ("Producto c", 3))
cur.execute(query, ("Producto d", 4))
cur.execute(query, ("Producto e", 5))
cur.execute(query, ("Producto f", 6))
con.commit()

query_patt = """
    SELECT
        Producto,
        Numero_de_serie
    FROM test WHERE Numero_de_serie IN ({}) 
    """

lista = [1, 2, 5, 4]

query = query_patt.format(','.join('?' * len(lista)))
cur.execute(query, lista)
print(cur.fetchall())

cur.close()
con.close()
os.remove("test_db.sqlite3")
```

Comment: Funciona! Gracias por tu respuesta. La cosa queda así adaptada a mi código:


    `lista = [6575,7567,4545,6766,444,6565,66,54545,65456,666,1233]
    consulta.execute("""SELECT Producto, Numero_de_serie, Fecha 
    FROM test WHERE (Numero_de_serie IN ({})).format(','.join('?' *                                                                                                     len(lista))),lista)`

Comment: Siento que el código sea algo ilegible pero no me está funcionando lo de los 4 espacios para formatear el comentario.

Comment: Otra cosa que también funciona:
Funciona! Gracias por tu respuesta. La cosa queda así adaptada a mi código: 

    `lista = [6575,7567,4545,6766,444,6565,66,54545,65456,666,1233]
    consulta.execute("""SELECT Producto, Numero_de_serie, Fecha 
    FROM test WHERE (Numero_de_serie IN {})""".format(str(tuple(listaNumSerie))))`

Comment: En el comentario donde he puesto que funciona, faltan las tres `"""` por lo que quedaría asi:  `(Numero_de_serie IN ({}))""".format` y en el comentario anterior a este, cambiar `listaNumSerie` por `lista`. Esto de que no te deje editar pasados los 5 minutos es un completo error. Casi no te da opción a tener ningún error bajo pena de tener que añadir comentarios adicionales.

Comment: Hola Toni, la segunda  `(."""... Numero_de_serie IN {})""".format(str(tuple(listaNumSerie)))))` funciona pero no parametrizas la query por lo que dependiendo de donde venga la tupla puede ser peligroso por ser susceptible de ataques de inyección de código. Si se usa hay que estar seguro de que la lista es segura o sanearla primero ya que en este caso SQL no nos protege. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias. Lo tendré en cuenta.