# Como hacer un SELECT IN con SQFLITE desde una lista de valores?

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, sqflite

Tengo un `List<String>` con nombres de titulos (los titulos pueden contener palabras o frases), y quiero consultar en mi base de datos todos los campos que contengan esos titulos exactos.

Al parecer tengo erores de sintaxis de SQFlite, tal vez no esté correctamente escrita la sentencia tipo `SELECT FROM WHERE IN`

Este es el codigo:

```
Future<List<curso>> misFavoritos() async {
    final db = await initializeDB();

    //puede contener mas valores desde posicion [0] hasta posicion [n]
    List<String>? listTitles = ['titulo1', 'titulo2', 'titulo numero 3']; 
    print(listTitles); //out: [titulo1, titulo2, titulo numero 3]
          
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> queryResult = await db.rawQuery(
        'SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE title IN ${List.filled(listTitles!.length, '?').join(',')}');

    Map<String, dynamic> result = {};

    for (var r in queryResult) {
      result.addAll(r);
    }

    print("result: $result");

    return queryResult.map((e) => curso.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }
```

Este es el error que me sale:

```
Error: DatabaseException(near "?": syntax error (code 1):,
while compiling: SELECT*FROM cursos WHERE title
IN ?,?,?) sql 'SELECT FROM cursos WHERE title IN ?,?,?
args[]

Exception has occurred.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE title IN ?,?,?) sql 'SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE title IN ?,?,?' args [])
```

Esta podría ser una ayuda para lograr una correcta sintaxis pero está en codigo python con SQLite: [Cómo hacer un WHERE IN con una lista de múltiples valores?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/199113/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-where-in-con-una-lista-de-m%c3%baltiples-valores?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Logré dar solución al error de sintaxis, por una manera alternativa de implementar el script SQL:

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> queryFavorites = await db.query(
  'cursos',
  where: " title IN (${listTitles!.map((_) => '?').join(', ')})",
  whereArgs: listTitles,
);
```

fuente: https://icedtealabs.com/til/flutter-sqlite-query-in/